# Performance of firefox vs chrome when loading large amount of nodes in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, dom

I am writing an Web application in which large amount of text is brought to the client side for processing and then converted as  Something.... and dumped into DOM .

I am using ajax query from jquery.

```
    $.ajax({
                 xhr: function () {
                     var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                     xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                         if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                             var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total * 100;
                             $("#fetchProgress").attr("value", percentComplete);
                         }
                     }, false);
                     return xhr;
                 },
                 type: 'GET',
                 url: "/GetSomething",
                 data: {},
                 success: function (data) {
                    ///process and dump to DOM//
                 var fileLines = data.split('\n');
                 var htmlString = '';
                 for (var i = 0; i < fileLines.length; i++) {
                     if (i == (highlightLine - 1)) {
                         htmlString += '<span id="highLoc" style="display:block"><font size="4" color="red">' + (i + 1) + '. ' + fileLines[i] + '</font></span>';
                     } else {
                         htmlString += '<span class="spanClass">' + (i + 1) + '. ' + fileLines[i];
                     }

                     if ((i % 1000) == 0) {

                         $("#textPlace").append(htmlString);
                         htmlString = '';
                     }

                 }
                 fileLines = null;

                 $("#textPlace").append(htmlString);



}
    });
```

When the javascript executes in chrome it takes double the time it takes to be rendered in firefox. Also, chrome become irresponsive while code executes. but same is not happening with firefox.

what should i do to make it wok in chrome?? Any help is appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: I think we should see what your success function does. Can you process the text as Something on the server?

Comment: It's hard to say why your function takes longer to execute in chrome than in firefox without seeing the actual code. For the unresponsiveness issue you could try throttling the rendering. It will take a bit longer, but would add to the DOM bit by bit giving an illusion of faster response.

Comment: @Jonas hi, i have updated the success function . we doing all the processing to the file at client side.

Comment: I think you should definitively move that logic to the server side. Also note that you're giving the same id to many elements on the same page (span id="highLoc") which is bad.

Comment: @jonas I searched on the web and found that chrome has some rendering issue.

Comment: ++ fact : firefox is still rendering faster than chrome.

Comment: Don't expect the user to have a super fast computer with chrome installed. Move the logic to the server, I think it's the only way to go in this case